# why does the ubuntu download page give me an AMD64 build when I choose 64b?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

When I select `64 bit (for newer machines)` and hit download, I get `ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso`. Is this to be expected, or an error? I want to install 64b Ubuntu 12.04 LTS into a VM in a 64b Windows 7 machine. The processor is *not* an AMD so I wonder if I have the right version.

Comment: `amd64` isn't AMD-only, it's just the standard architecture name used to denote 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 3):

it's called amd64 because AMD developed it. Intel developed the old x86 base. This is primarily divided so none of the companies can rule the market and limit it's usage.

the amd64 will work any any cpu that is 64-bit capable.

Comment: @Jcollum well did a school project about the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit :)

Comment: Being pedantic here there are 64-bit processors that are not AMD/Intel compatible. But, if your PC could run 64-bit Windows you can use the **amd64** image even if the processor is not **amd**.

Comment: @WarrenHill Yes not everything is supported by the X86_64 platform, but if you have hardware that isn't supported by that architecture then you you know so much about the subject so you can make the choice on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Standard computers run x86 architecture cpus, which can be divided into:

1. X86-16, meaning 16bit,
2. X86-32, meaning 32bit, which is often refered to as x86 or i386 or IA-32 (Intel Architecture 32bit)
3. X86-64, meaning 64bit, which is often refered to as amd64

The reason that many people refer to X86-64 as amd64 is that AMD developed it, which personally I think is not a good enough reason to call it that, after all Intel developed IA64 (Itanium Architecture) and you don't see anyone calling it intel64.

Needless to say, that software designed for amd64 is not limited to amd brand cpus, it will run on any X86-64 cpu.

Comment: well IA64 isn't used in that much. Mostly servers, most computers use the 32-bit x86 or the 64 bit x86-64 extension, developed by AMD.